# Error bars with color on pgf plots

Tags: pgfplots

I was trying to make my error bars the same color as I have for my data on pgf-plot. The method was greatly explained earlier here - [Define error bar color in scatter class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113289/define-error-bar-color-in-scatter-class?rq=1)

My code at the beginning

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={time, $s$},
ylabel={fraction},
ymin=0, ymax=1,
grid=major,
legend entries={$16nt$,$40nt$,$62nt$},
]
\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
  16nt={mark=square*,blue},
  40nt={mark=triangle*,red},
  62nt={mark=*,draw=black}
  },
error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,
y explicit
]
table[x=x, y=y,y error = err, meta=label, row sep=crcr] {
x      y      err    label\\
0.1    0.15   0.1    16nt\\
0.45   0.27   0.1    16nt\\
0.02   0.17   0.1    16nt\\
0.06   0.1    0.1    16nt\\
0.9    0.5    0.1    40nt\\
0.5    0.3    0.1    40nt\\
0.85   0.52   0.1    40nt\\
0.12   0.05   0.1    40nt\\
0.73   0.45   0.1    62nt\\
0.53   0.25   0.1    62nt\\
0.76   0.5    0.1    62nt\\
0.55   0.32   0.1    62nt\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{trial plot}
\end{figure}
```

But when I change

```
error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,
y explicit` by `error bars with color=err
```

as it was stated in the mentioned answer and add

```
error bars with color/.style={
visualization depends on=\thisrow{#1} \as \error,
visualization depends on=y \as \y,
scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={ % Homebrew color bars
        \draw (0,0) -- +(axis direction cs:0,-\error) -- +(axis direction cs:0,\error);
        \draw (0,0) plot [mark=-] coordinates {(axis direction cs:0,\error) (axis direction cs:0,-\error)};
},
error bars/.cd, % Invisible color bars, to get the right axis limits
        y dir=both,
        y explicit,
        error bar style={opacity=0},
/pgfplots/.cd
}
```

I can't compile my document because it shows the mistake in line with     `\end{axis}`

with message

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry[grouping levels=255].\pgfmth@float@parse#1->\begingroup\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/pgf/fpu/output form... \end{axis}

What does it mean?
Sorry if question is stupid, I am new at LaTex and really stacked on this!