# scatter, group, error bar, and a legend

Tags: pgfplots

I want a grouped scatter plot with xy error bars and a legend. So each point is a different group, with its own color, mark, and legend entry. The error bars should have the same color as the mark they belong to.

Here is an edited example from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34681/12370) answer:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    error bars with mapped color/.style={
        disabledatascaling,
        visualization depends on=\thisrow{#1} \as \error,
        visualization depends on=\thisrow{y} \as \y,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
            /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
            error mark options={draw=mapped color},
            error mark=|,
            draw error bar={(0,0)}{(0,\error*100)}, % *100 to correct for the scaling
            draw error bar={(0,0)}{(0,-\error*100)} % might have to be adjusted (0.1,1,10,100,...)
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.append code={}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
             scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color, fill=mapped color},
         scatter/classes={ a={mark=*,draw=red,fill=red!50},b={mark=square*,draw=green,fill=green!50},c={mark=triangle*,draw=magenta,fill=magenta!50} }
         ]
\addplot [
    scatter,
    only marks,
    scatter src=\thisrow{class},
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    error bars with mapped color=err,
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
] 
      table[x=x,y=y,y error=err,meta=meta] {
x y err class meta
0 0 1   0  a
1 1 .1   0  a
2 0 1   1  b
3 -.5 .2   2  c
};
\legend{Worlds,People,Barnacles}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But you'll notice that the "brackets" of the error bars are not colored correctly. I haven't managed creating x-error bars at the same time.

Maybe, by now, there is an altogether better solution than @Jake suggested?

[image]

Comment: Although I stated that I wanted only one point per group, I erroneously plotted two points for the World group (in red).

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33862/error-bar-colors-in-scatter-plot) post would seem to answer your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the following, while very ugly, works relatively well:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{myerr/.append style={only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit, x dir=both,x explicit} }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[myerr] coordinates { (0,0) +- (0.5,0.1)};
\addlegendentryexpanded{Worlds}
\addplot+[myerr] coordinates { (-1,1) +- (0.7,1.1)};
\addlegendentryexpanded{People}
\addplot+[myerr] coordinates { (-2,4) +- (2.7,2.1)};
\addlegendentryexpanded{Barnacles}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I just added an `addplot` with error details per point. Colors, legend, etc are taken care of by `pgfplots`, and I can automate this type of code from the same program I use to generate the data points (in my case, `Julia`).